# HTML - split the array values dynamically using comma seperated

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs

Using `ng-repeat` am showing array of values which am getting it from backend. But i want to split the specific values using comma seperated and displya it dynamically.

Please find the HTML code below.

```
<li ng-repeat="history in claimGroupingHistories">
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
              <label>{{'claimgroup.history.oldvalueselected'|translate}}:</label>
            </div>
            <div id="historyOldValueSelected_{{$index}}" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">{{history.oldValueSelected}}</div>
            </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

Here, in the `{{history.oldValueSelected}}` values will be like `ABC1234, XYZ2345, IJK098`. Instead of showing the value in single line. I want to split the value using comma seperated and display the value.

For Example :

Now, it showing like,

```
Old Value Selected : ABC1234, XYZ2345, IJK098
```

Expecting output like,

```
Old Value Selected : ABC1234
                     XYZ2345
                     IJK098
```

Splitting the array values dynamically using comma seperated.

Testdata :

```
[  
{  
  "id":null,
  "dealerCode":"T030",
  "oldValueSelected":null,
  "newValueSelected":"Group by minimum claims, Customer Invoice or Repair Date",
  "createdBy":"System Admin",
  "createdAt":"2019-01-23T06:13:00.000Z",
  "lastModifiedAt":"2019-01-22T18:42:59.000Z"
},
{  
  "id":null,
  "dealerCode":"T030",
  "oldValueSelected":"Group by minimum claims, Customer Invoice or Repair Date",
  "newValueSelected":"Group by minimum claims",
  "createdBy":"System Admin",
  "createdAt":"2019-01-23T06:13:00.000Z",
  "lastModifiedAt":"2019-01-23T06:13:07.000Z"
},
{  
  "id":null,
  "dealerCode":"T030",
  "oldValueSelected":"Group by minimum claims",
  "newValueSelected":"Group by minimum claims, Customer Invoice No",
  "createdBy":"System Admin",
  "createdAt":"2019-01-23T06:13:00.000Z",
  "lastModifiedAt":"2019-01-23T06:14:54.000Z"
},
{  
  "id":null,
  "dealerCode":"T030",
  "oldValueSelected":"Group by minimum claims, Customer Invoice No",
  "newValueSelected":null,
  "createdBy":"System Admin",
  "createdAt":"2019-01-23T06:13:00.000Z",
  "lastModifiedAt":"2019-01-24T06:23:33.000Z"
},
{  
  "id":null,
  "dealerCode":"T030",
  "oldValueSelected":null,
  "newValueSelected":"Customer Invoice No, Group by minimum claims",
  "createdBy":"System Admin",
  "createdAt":"2019-01-23T06:13:00.000Z",
  "lastModifiedAt":"2019-01-24T06:23:58.000Z"
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming history.oldValueSelected is a string, because if oldValueSelected was an array you could use ng-repeat like this:

```
<div layout="column">
    <span ng-repeat="oldValue in history.oldValueSelected" ng-bind="oldValue"></span>
</div>
```

Now to oldValueSelected being a string. I can think of two options: You can either

- split the values in the controller after you got your data
- split it in ng-repeat

If you choose the second option, you can do the following:

```
<div layout="column">
    <span ng-repeat="oldValue in history.oldValueSelected.split(', ')" ng-bind="oldValue"></span>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I didn't get the expected output when I used **class="row"**

```
<li ng-repeat="history in $ctrl.histories">
    <!-- class="row" didn't deliver the expected output-->
    <div layout="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <!--  For testing purposes - replace with your code-->
            <label>{{history.name}}:</label>
        </div>
        <div layout="column">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8" ng-repeat="oldValue in history.oldValueSelected.split(', ')">{{oldValue}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

In the controller for testing purposes:

```
this.histories = [
    {name: "number 1", oldValueSelected:"ABC1234, XYZ2345, IJK098"},
    {name: "number 2", oldValueSelected:"ABC1234, IJK098"},
    {name: "number 3", oldValueSelected:"IJK098"}
];
```

Comment: I have modified in this way., but still its not working as expected `<div ng-repeat="oldValue in history.oldValueSelected.split(', ')" ng-bind="oldValue" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8span">{{history.oldValueSelected}}</div>`. Where am going wrong here?

Comment: Have tried with this code also `<div layout="column" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8div"><span ng-repeat="oldValue in history.oldValueSelected.split(', ')" ng-bind="oldValue"></span></div>` . but no luck.

Comment: @Karthikeyan That should split the string in an array, you would need to add a container/wrapper like i did with `<div layout="column">`. Because divs are block-level elements, your div with ng-repeat should break - otherwise you can try to add `display: block; `
Edit: I inserted the code of your second comment and got the expected output. Can you try it with class="column"?

Comment: Tried with `<div layout="column">` its not working., how to do with `display: block;`

Comment: I tried it with your code and didn't get the expected output. I changed class="row" to layout="row" and the output was like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zYM7lz97jCtpGHQX_YpcsA72dG8kHKAv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Take a look at the edit. I changed it to your structure and replaced in the parent div `class="row"` with `layout="row"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187254/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-guest).

Comment: In my case, `.split()` is not working., i have updated my test data.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.component.html
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes.split(', ')">
 {{ hero }}
</div>

app.component.ts
private  heroes: string = "123123, 123123, 345354, 5675757";
```

Output:

```
123123
123123
345354
5675757
```